# Visual Studio C++ aggressive intellisense ignores spacebar

Tags: c++, visual-studio, intellisense

I know this question was asked few times before but there is still no answer. Is there a way to make c++ editor behave like c# one so that it commits intellisense selection when I press spacebar? I've set member list to be aggressive and it works for all characters in "{}.,:;+-*/%&|^!=<>?@#\ " except for space. I can commit with spacebar if I press ctrl+spacebar before but I want it to be more automatic, like in c#. I'm using VS2017 but in 2015 it's the same story.

Comment: Just found out it works with classes, if I put a dot after object name, start typing something and press space it autocompletes but still doesn't work on a fresh line.

Comment: What's wrong with Ctrl + Spacebar. You are hitting space anyways.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to your description, I tested it in my VS 2017 and got the same result as yours, I have reported it to the VS Product Team, please check this: [VS 2017 > C++ > Intellisense: Committed by press the space bar not works even if set “Disable Aggressive Member List” to “True”](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/72187/vs-2017-c-intellisense-committed-by-press-the-spac.html) and you can vote it or add your comments, then we need to wait for the response from the VS Product Team, thank you for your understanding.